# Generic class instantiation using a bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

Based on the code snippet listed in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75499300/1818935) (copied from a Java tutorial on generics by Gilad Bracha), I wrote the following code which tries to populate a custom generic list called `history` with objects of different types conforming to the bound `? extends Shape`. However, my program doesn't compile. Why? How is it different from the code snippet in my other question?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Shape {}
class Circle extends Shape {}
class Rectangle extends Shape {}

class MyArrayList<T>
{
    private ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public T get(int idx)
    {
        return items.get(idx);
    }

    public void add(T item)
    {
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "A box of [";
        for (T item : items) { str += item; }
        str += ']';
        return str;
    }
}

public class Shapes
{
    private static MyArrayList<? extends Shape>
       history = new MyArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        history.add(new Circle());
        history.add(new Rectangle());
        System.out.println(history);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*How is it different from the code snippet in my other question?*" Please keep everything relevant to the question in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your previous example, you had a `List<List<? extends Shape>>`. Here you have a `List<? extends Shape>`. Completely different things.

Given a `MyArrayList<? extends Shape>`, that is a *REFERENCE* (like a page in an address book, not like a house), and the 'page in the address book' (that'd be your variable) promises that the house you get to will be guaranteed to be one of a few different style. Specifically, it'll be a `List<Shape>`. Or it could be a `List<Rectangle>`. Or perhaps a `List<Circle>`. But it'll be either a list of all sorts of shapes, or a list of some sort of specific shape.

This is different from just 'it's a list of all sorts of shapes' - that would be a `List<Shape>`, not a `List<? extends Shape>`.

Given that it *could be* a list of circles, and it could also be a list of squares, **everything** you do with `history` needs to be a thing you could do to either one.

`.add(new Circle())` is not something that is valid for a `List<Rectangle>`. Hence, you can't do that, and `history.add(new Circle())` is a compilation error.

So why did the previous snippet work? Because that was about `List<List<? extends Shape>>` which is a completely different thing to a `List<? extends Shape>`. One stores shapes. One stores a list of shapes.